# Postfix email rejected

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I've a postfix running for years without problems, but I've a recipient who doesn't recieve my mails.

Here is the error log :

```
Jan 19 04:17:02 server05 postfix/smtp[25826]: 7A2C34023F: to=<xxx@yyy.com>, 
relay=sssss.net[111.111.111.111]:25, delay=298684, delays=298676/0.01/2.3/6.3, dsn=4.1.7, 
status=deferred (host sssss.net[111.111.111.111] said: 450 4.1.7 <www-data@my_domain.fr>: 
Sender address rejected: unverified address: connect to my_domain.fr[222.22.5.5]:25: No route to host (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Any ideas ?

My posfix configuration

```
# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 20971520
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = my_domain.fr
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
```

Answer (score 0):

When verification takes too long the Postfix SMTP server defers the sender or recipient address with a 450 reply. Normal mail clients will connect again after some delay.

The unverified_sender_reject_code parameter (default 450) specifies the numerical Postfix server reply code when a sender address is known to bounce. Change this setting into 550 when you trust Postfix's judgments.

Refer this [link](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html) to change the settings of main.cf as per your requirements

Comment: I've changed my conf, but, same problem... (I've added conf to my question)

Answer (score 0):

Often many mail servers rejects connections from domains hasn't a register DNS inverse. This is solved adding a PTR record to you domain from your ISP. Other way is configure BIND if you are the system administrator, so you can redirect dns record to your server.

I found a thread of forum about this issue, but you can find much more:
https://serverfault.com/questions/148178/reverse-dns-the-reason-my-mails-are-rejected

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is network reachability (or alternatively, firewall) problem.
The clue is "*connect to my_domain.fr[222.22.5.5]:25: **No route to host***"

It means that your machine cannot connect to `222.22.5.5` on TCP port `25`.
Which means that `telnet 222.22.5.5 25` run from command line will also fail.

There could be two reasons for that:

1. **some firewall between you and `222.22.5.5` is blocking connections to port 25** - you can check by trying to connect to some other port the destination machine is running, like `telnet 222.22.5.5 80` if he is running web server, or using port `465` for SMTPS if he has that  etc. It could also be [IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) at his side has marked your IP as attacker for some reason and is blocking you. You could also try `ping 222.22.5.5`. If none of that works, it is more likely that problem is next reason
2. there is network problem between you and destination host. You can usually use `traceroute -n 222.22.5.5` to determine approximately where the problem is. It could be for various reasons; if `222.22.5.5` is [AS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28Internet%29) and none of his other addresses are reachable, it could be BGP routing problem. Or there is static route somewhere pointing to wrong place. Or the recipient is running on cluster and only some nodes are problematic. Depending if traceroute above fails near you or near him, yours or his ISP should be able (if they're willing - usually you're more likely to get lucky if they are small or if you're big customer) to help troubleshoot it (and even fix if problem is with them, or workaround by routing via different ASs if it is isn't their problem)